# Register new place google places via API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places

Is it possible to register new place in google place via google maps API?

I have searched on the documentation and found nothing. Some stackoverflow questions on this were getting no response.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that it is possible to add a business place via the API. If you want to add a new place to Google Places, you will have to register it manually.

[Here](http://www.wikihow.com/Add-Places-to-Google-Maps) you can find a tutorial of how to add places to Google Maps.